# how to replace both the content of DIV and class name

Tags: jquery

I want to locate a div  and replace both the content and div class name with another, how to do that

```
<div class="replaceme1"> 
  replace me 2, too
```

Comment: What do you want the result to look like?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$("div.replaceme1")
    .html("<p>new text</p>")
    .removeClass("replaceme1")
    .addClass("SomeNewClassReplacement");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use the jQuery library, check out:

1. The [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or .html() attribute to modify it's content;
2. The [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and .removeClass() attribute;
   or
3. The [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) attribute;

to modify it's class.
Note that the latter will require you to use quotes.

So, for your example, you would do:

```
$('div.replaceme1')
    .removeClass('BottomSmMargin MiniCheckDiv')
    .text('Hello world!');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.replaceme1')
    .removeClass('replaceme1')
    .addClass('Foo')
    .html('<p>Some new text</p>')
```

Have a read of [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/), [.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [.addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace everything:

```
$('#replace_this').after('#to_this').remove();
```